# Drupal - Heartbeat activity - only showing activity wher a users is, the owner OR a member

Tags: drupal

Wondering if anyone knows how to create a view that only shows the activity of groups, where the current logged in user, is either the owner OR a member.

thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can in views add an argument, and select the logged in user. You can use that to query whatever groups you are talking about.